# alsa/timidity doesn't recognize default device with user root and in init.d on Debian 10

Tags: debian, audio, pulseaudio, alsa, timidity

In Debian 10, When I start `timidity` as alsa sequencer with a normal user, no problem at all. It works flawlessy.

```
samuele@INSPIRON-17:~$ timidity -Os -iA
Requested buffer size 32768, fragment size 8192
ALSA pcm 'default' set buffer size 32768, period size 8192 bytes
TiMidity starting in ALSA server mode
Opening sequencer port: 128:0 128:1 128:2 128:3
```

When I switch to `root` user, it dosen't works anymore:

```
root@INSPIRON-17:~# timidity -Os -iA
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Can't open pcm device 'default'.
Couldn't open ALSA pcm device (`s')
```

It seems it cannot finde the "default" device. I know I can forcing it creating an `~/.asoundrc` file or a global `/etc/asound.conf`, but the normal user dosen't need it. It seems it's accessing the global `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf`, while `root` dosen't.

So my question is: how i can fix that without writing a new config file? Is it possible to let `root` access the global file, or I'm missing something?

The system is running Debian 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i have solved it.
It's a mix of design and permission problem.

According to `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf`, all conf from `/etc/alsa/conf.d` are loaded. There we have a `99-pulse.conf`, linked to `/usr/share/alsa/pulse-alsa.conf`.
In this last file, `pulse` is set as default alsa device when `pulseaudio` is started, and it's not started at boot time, but only when a user login.

Root can't use timidity mainly because he lacks the privilege to access pulse, and this is the first permission problem.

Event trying to start timidity as a service after a user login it's not working, because the init script provided by the package `timidity-daemon` is trying (through start-stop-daemon) to start the process as the user timidity, but this behavior it's not allowed, and this is the second permission problem. 
And because of root missing permissions, even changing the script cutting away the user-changing part it's not working.
The only mistery (to me) is that just after installing the package timidity-daemon, the permission problem is not happening, but after the first restart it stops to works.

Anyway, it can be fixed in two ways.

The first, simple and less-invasive solution is to don't use the package `timidity-daemon` at all, but to create a custom `timidity.service` file located under `/usr/lib/systemd/user/`.

before install the needed packages

```
sudo apt-get install timidity fluid-soundfont-gm
```

then create the file (with sudo) `/usr/lib/systemd/user/timidity.service` with this content

```
[Unit]
Description=Timidity
After=pulseaudio.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/timidity -Os -iA

[Install]
WantedBy=pulseaudio.service
```

now install and start it

```
systemctl --user enable timidity.service
systemctl --user start timidity.service
```

and it's done.

The second solution is to start pulse at boot time system-wide and to allow root and timidity to use it, not the best choice from a security point of view. 
Anyway, in order to get pulse/timidity to work as root system-wide, those are the steps: (inspired by https://raven4.cz/wp/pulseaudio-in-system-wide-mode/)

first install base packages

```
sudo apt-get install timidity timidity-daemon fluid-soundfont-gm
```

edit (with sudo) `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`, search the row

```
; system-instance = no
```

uncomment it and set it to yes

```
system-instance = yes
```

now remove the file `/etc/pulse/system.pa` and  symlink default.pa as system.pa

```
sudo rm /etc/pulse/system.pa
sudo ln -s /etc/pulse/default.pa /etc/pulse/system.pa
```

now edit (sudo) `/etc/pulse/default.pa`, find the row

```
load-module module-native-protocol-unix
```

and change it this way

```
load-module module-native-protocol-unix auth-group-enable=true auth-group=pulse-access socket=/tmp/pulse-socket
```

now edit (sudo) `/etc/pulse/client.conf`, find the row

```
; default-server =
```

uncomment it and set it this way

```
default-server = unix:/tmp/pulse-socket
```

now we need to add every user we want have access to pulseaudio in the account `pulse-access`. `timidity` will run as his own user, so we need to add it too.
In my case i want the user `root` and my main user, `samuele`, so i'll do:

```
usermod -a -G pulse-access root
usermod -a -G pulse-access samuele
usermod -a -G pulse-access timidity
```

now we need to create the custom `pulseaudio.service` file.
so create a file in `/etc/systemd/system/pulseaudio.service` with this content

```
[Unit]
Description=Pulseaudio

[Service]
User=root
Type=forking
ExecStart=/bin/pulseaudio --realtime --daemonize
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Now it's time to fix timidity.

Check if it's working with

```
aconnect -lo | grep -i timidity
```

if not, start it

```
sudo service timidity start
```

check again, if everything it's working, whe have a generated service file in `/run/systemd/generator.late/timidity.service`

copy it to `/etc/systemd/system`

```
sudo cp /run/systemd/generator.late/timidity.service /etc/systemd/system/timidity.service
```

now edit it (sudo) and in the file beginning search for

```
After=remote-fs.target
```

and change it this way

```
After=remote-fs.target pulseaudio.service
```

In file ending add those two lines to make it installable

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now it's time for cleaning.
stop timidity and remove it from init.d

```
sudo service timidity stop
sudo update-rc.d -f timidity remove
```

stop the per-user pulseaudio, disable it and clean your userdir config

```
systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.socket
systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.service
systemctl --user disable pulseaudio.socket
systemctl --user disable pulseaudio.service
rm -Rf ~/.config/pulse/
```

now enable the new services

```
sudo systemctl enable /etc/systemd/system/pulseaudio.service
sudo systemctl enable /etc/systemd/system/timidity.service
```

restart the machine aaaand.. it's done!